# Line break a word onto a full line if it contains a hyphen

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-break, css-hyphens

I am attempting to use javascript so when my h1 element gets to the end of a line if it contains a hyphened word it line breaks the whole word onto the next line so it stops the below.

**Issue below**

[image: Issue at hand]

**i want the result to be**

```
Product T Hydra 2000
e-Ticket
```

This is the javascript I have so far which pushes it onto the next line but this happens for every hyphened word regardless of where it sits within the h1.

```js
let infoBox = document.querySelector('.viewer__info-box');
let h1Element = document.querySelector('.viewer__h1');


let words = h1Element.innerText.split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if (words[i].includes('-')) {
    words[i] = '<br>' + words[i];
  }
}
console.log(words.join(' '));
h1Element.innerHTML = words.join(' ');
```

I've tried using below to check the width of the div against the content but had no luck.

```
if (h1Element.scrollWidth <= h1Element.clientWidth) {
```

has anyone got any ideas on this?

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my end, maybe recheck if there's any issue.

Comment: @trincot so if a single line gets to the end and the last word contains a hyphen that whole word needs breaking to the next line. My current solution just line breaks wherever a hyphened word is presented

Comment: Replace all your hyphens with non-breaking ones (`‑`  i.e. \u2011)

Comment: @ProDeSquare Yeah it line breaks wherever a hyphened word appears though - it should only happen at the end of the line

Comment: @trincot wow why did I not think of that it looks more or less identical to the default - on ones keyboard thanks!

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace any standard hyphens with non-breaking hyphens.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('h1').forEach(h1 => {
  h1.innerHTML = h1.innerHTML.replace('-','\u2011')
})
```

```html
<h1>Product T Hydra 2000 e-Ticket</h1>
```